# Finding optimal combination of elements that minimizes evaluation function

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

The optimal grouping of elements is that in which the evaluation function is the smallest.

Wherein:

- each group must have a fixed number of elements - N=3,
- all elements of the sequence must necessarily be included in some group,
- there are 24 elements
- each element can be used once
- each element is described by three values ​​(id - number, ValueA, ValueB).

Each distribution of elements into groups is described by an evaluation function:

1. V = E + C,
2. E = MAX (sum (ValueA)) - Min (sum (ValueA)), where sum    (ValueA) is
   the sum of ValueА of one group
3. С = avg (c1, C2, c3),    where c1 = ABS (SUM (ValueA) - Sum
   (ValueB)) - group 1

I have tried bruteforce method , but it seems it would take ages to complete.  What is the name of problems like that ? It looks like linear programming problem, but i might be wrong. If i could know type of problem , i would probably be able to research on my own.

Comment: The definition of your 'C' variable seems unclear. Can you give an example of evaluating V for a single input group? Also, you mention a 'battery' element; what's that?

Comment: Battery is just a simple element, i forgot to delete this part. For each constructed group there is C value calculated , for example lets say have group with elements a,b,c . C1=ABS(a.ValueA+b.ValueA+c.ValueA-a.ValueB-b.ValueB-c.ValueB) . After calculating C value of each group i should get their average .  
E=groups.ForEach(x=>x.GetSumA()).Max()-groups.ForEach(x=>x.GetSumA()).Min()